# How to change Faker date format to yield date in "DD/MM/YYYY" format?

Tags: ruby, faker

I am using [Faker](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/master/doc/default/date.md) to generate a random Birthdate and feed the same in a Date input box in **DD/MM/YYYY** format through my automation script.

I tried this below snippet, however, it returns a date in **YYYY/MM/DD** format. I tried changing the **from** and **to** date format to **DD/MM/YYYY** as well, but no luck.

```
  def self.get_birth_date
    Faker::Date.between(from: '1950/01/01', to: '2001/12/31')
  end
```

Would appreciate, if someone from the group can help. Thanks!

Comment: That method returns a `Date` object, which is totally fine. Your question is about how to **present** that `Date` object (as a `String`) in the desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use strftime method:

```
Faker::Date.between(from: '1950/01/01', to: '2001/12/31').strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

It will return "29/05/1969"

Comment: OP did not mention rails... But **if** this is rails, note that you can also use `.to_s(:name_of_the_format)` to specify custom time formats with reduced repetition. https://apidock.com/rails/Date/to_formatted_s